# Binding element 'index' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular2-mdl

Using the [demo project of angular2-mdl](https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/blob/master/src/demo-app/app/tabs/tabs.component.ts) as a guide I ported the tab component and tried to implement it as follow:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './landing.my.html'
})
export class MyDashboard {
    public activeIndex = 0;

    public tabChanged({index}): void {
        this.activeIndex = index;
    }

}
```

and the template is:

```
<mdl-tabs mdl-ripple mdl-tab-active-index="0" (mdl-tab-active-changed)="tabChanged($event)">
    <mdl-tab-panel mdl-tab-panel-title="home">
        <mdl-tab-panel-title>
            <mdl-icon class="mdl-color-text--primary">home</mdl-icon><span>Home</span>
        </mdl-tab-panel-title>
        <mdl-tab-panel-content>
            <ul>
                <li>Stanis</li>
                <li>Joffrey</li>
            </ul>
        </mdl-tab-panel-content>
    </mdl-tab-panel>
    <mdl-tab-panel mdl-tab-panel-title="something">
        <mdl-tab-panel-title>
            <mdl-icon class="mdl-color-text--primary">group_work</mdl-icon><span>Ontology</span>
        </mdl-tab-panel-title>
        <mdl-tab-panel-content>
            <ul>
                <li>Stanis</li>
                <li>Joffrey</li>
            </ul>
        </mdl-tab-panel-content>
    </mdl-tab-panel>
    <mdl-tab-panel mdl-tab-panel-title="another">
        <mdl-tab-panel-title>
            <mdl-icon class="mdl-color-text--primary">list</mdl-icon><span>Cognitive</span>
        </mdl-tab-panel-title>
        <mdl-tab-panel-content>
            <ul>
                <li>Robert</li>
            </ul>
        </mdl-tab-panel-content>
    </mdl-tab-panel>
    <mdl-tab-panel mdl-tab-panel-title="else">
        <mdl-tab-panel-title>
            <mdl-icon class="mdl-color-text--primary">call_split</mdl-icon><span>Cognition</span>
        </mdl-tab-panel-title>
        <mdl-tab-panel-content>
            <ul>
                <li>Robert</li>
                <li>Renly</li>
            </ul>
        </mdl-tab-panel-content>
    </mdl-tab-panel>
    <mdl-tab-panel mdl-tab-panel-title="last">
        <mdl-tab-panel-title>
            <mdl-icon class="mdl-color-text--primary">backup</mdl-icon><span>Streaming</span>
        </mdl-tab-panel-title>
        <mdl-tab-panel-content>
            <ul>
                <li>Joffrey</li>
                <li>Myrcella</li>
                <li>Tommen</li>
            </ul>
        </mdl-tab-panel-content>
    </mdl-tab-panel>
</mdl-tabs>
```

I am using webpack, and i get the following error:

```
ERROR in [default] home/my-app-ui/src/app/landing.my.ts:10:23 
Binding element 'index' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

however the app displays the desired functionality, can someone explain how to fix this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use `any` or specific type of the variable like ( numbers,string,etc )

```
public tabChanged(index:any): void {
    this.activeIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: For this function much better to declare index:number

Comment: this seems to be the simplest & best answer (especially given that it has the tick), but it didn't work for me; as now the variable I get is not a string anymore after I remove the braces

Answer (score 240):

For an object, you need to declare the type as:

```js
{index} : {index:any}
```

For objects with more props:

```js
{a,b} : {a:any, b:any}
```

Comment: What do you do if your array looks like this though: { component, ...props }
I've tried { component, ...props }: { component: any, props: any }, but that gave me errors with the props argument

Comment: Using `any` is like putting the dust under your rug. It will bite you in the future

Comment: Works for React TSX too!

Answer (score 39):

for an object, you need to declare like this way
with one prop:

```
{propA} : {propA:any}
```

with more than one prop:

```
{propA, propB} : {propA:any, propB:any}
```

Answer (score 30):

It is a check of the type script compiler. You can either remove the check or specify explicitly the any type in the declaration (answer from @Thyagu).
In the `tsconfig.json` file, you could change the line

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

to

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```

Comment: or the other way around?

Answer (score 4):

```
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true //tsconfig.json
```

You can set a variable's type to any even when the noImplicitAny flag is true.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a React Native, Typescript answer

```
const MainHome = ({props}:any) => {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` within `compilerOptions` in *tsconfig.json* file. Example:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
   "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following solution: go to the 'ts config.JSON' file in your project directory. Locate the 'strict' property within the file and change its value from 'true' to 'false'. This modification relaxes some of the strict Type Script compiler checks, which might help resolve the problem you're facing. However, keep in mind that disabling strict checks may lead to potential type errors or decreased code quality, so it's advisable to use this as a temporary fix and consider alternative solutions if possible. thanks