# How to fix Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm missing something here with the validation how to add types validation? Having error "element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type".

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from './Styles';

const Button1 = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>
);

Button1.propTypes = {};

export default Button1;
```

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings almost but not really, as that question is about propTypes and what the type should be, this one is about typescript and what causes this error.

Comment: Related answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745992/binding-element-index-implicitly-has-an-any-type/40746812#40746812

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Edit 2022:
with react 18, FC no longer provides children, so you have to type it yourself, and you can drop FC:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
    children?: ReactNode
    // any props that come into the component
}

const Button1 = ({ children, ...props }: Props) => (
    <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>
);
```

Yes you are missing a type for Props as whole, which means typescript sees it as `any` and your ts rules dont allow it.

You have to type your props as:

```
import React, { FC } from "react";

interface Props {
    // any props that come into the component
}

const Button1: FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>
);
```

Comment: Why is this called IProps and not just Props? (I am brand new to TS, I am not challenging just asking).

Comment: @FMD Its just naming, we used to type `I` in front of each name of interface, but with time we dont do that anymore.

Comment: Which imo is good to include, cuz sometimes we have a component with constants and such defined - the `I` for `Interface` in `IProps` etc. helps tell the difference.

Comment: React exposes PropsWithChildren so that can be used instead of creating your own Props interface

Comment: @NeveenAtik I personally dislike it, since children are always optional, and sometimes thats not what you want, but you do you.

Answer (score 43):

This was a major issue for me and I wasted a lot of time figuring out the correct solution.
Right now you have an error with the children prop but in the future, you might have this error for a lot of functions where you are destructuring the params.
So I would suggest, follow this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9657).

```
const yourfunc = ({destructuredProps}: {destructuredProps: type}) => {}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can also add the predefined type to your functional components like this:

```
const Button1: React.FC<{}>  = ({ children }) => (
    <Button>{children}</Button>
);
```

By this way you don't have to repeat yourself to define `children` props.

The fuller version could be like this:

```
interface Props {
// any other props that come into the component, you don't have to explicitly define children.
}

const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
      <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>
  );
};
```

Please note it works for **React 16.8**

Comment: How about functions comming from props, whihc type can you use in the interface declaration?

Comment: @JulianTorregrosa, we can have multiple ways to do it https://mariusschulz.com/articles/typing-functions-in-typescript

Answer (score 19):

As another approach, you can use the built-in generic type "React.PropsWithChildren" for children in props, taking those props accordingly. A very short code would look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Styles";

type MyComponentProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{}>;

export default function MyComponent({ children, ...other}: MyComponentProps) {
  return <Button {...other}>{children}</Button>;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

It needs 'any' so give it !

```
const Button1 = ({ children, ...props } : any)
```

Then handle it in function if you want to preserve the type

Answer (score 10):

You can use types as well

```
type ButtonProps = {
    children: ReactNode;
    
}

const Button = ({ children }: ButtonProps) => (
    <button>{children}</button>
);
```

Answer (score 6):

I find it best to have the component props interface extend from `React.HTMLAttributes` because it gives you the standard HTML attributes without any extra configuration:

```
interface Button1Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<Element> {
  // add any custom props, but don't have to specify `children`
}

const Button1 = ({ children, ...props }: Button1Props) => (
    <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>
)
```

If you want to enforce `children` to be provided, you can make it required by redefining it in the props interface:

```
interface Button1Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<Element> {
  children: React.ReactNode
  // add any custom props, but don't have to specify `children`
}

const Button1 = ({ children, ...props }: Button1Props) => (
    <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Also do this to stop error: **children?: React.ReactNode;**

```
export interface props {
    children?: React.ReactNode; }

const Screen = ({ children }: props) => {
    return (
        <div style={{ margin: '2%' }}>
            {children}
        </div>
    ); };

export default Screen;
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can be fixed by explicitly defining type for the variable (`children` in this case) and not leaving it to be implicitly inferred

Error can be stopped altogether with TypeScript `--noImplicitAny` [compiler option](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/typescript-error-ts7031-makes-me-go-huh-c81cf76c829b)

Answer (score 0):

One answer I found and wanted to share, but will probably be highly frowned upon, is that you can set `skipLibCheck` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json` within the `compilerOptions` object, and it will ignore the issue.

As a caveat, please ensure you know what you are doing when adding this rule. A good article about this is here:  https://www.testim.io/blog/typescript-skiplibcheck/

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically due to this issue, but related to it, because of the children prop:
The usage of React.FC discouraged and by now is officially removed from from Typescript template.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Answer (score -1):

Write this code, it shoud fix your problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2m6G.png)

Comment: Post the code example here