# Binding element 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type error in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a ReactJS project based on TypeScript. The following is one such file: Layout.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import NavigationBar from './navigation/NavigationBar';
import Footer from './footer/Footer';

const Layout = ({ title, description, children }) => {
     return (
          <>
               <Helmet>
                    <title>{title ? title + " - React Boilerplate" : "React.js Boilerplate"}</title>
                    <meta name="description" content={description || "React.js Boilerplate"} />
               </Helmet>
               <NavigationBar />
               <main className="container">
                    {children}
               </main>
               <Footer />
          </>
     );
}

export default Layout;
```

For this I am constantly getting: `Binding element 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type.` I tried solutions for this online, but all of them are for Javascript and seems not to match with mine. Help is appreciated here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding element 'index' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745992/binding-element-index-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 16):

You are missing typing for your component (your function).
First you have to tell TS that this is `FunctionalComponent` and second you have to tell it about its props.

Here is how you can do it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import NavigationBar from './navigation/NavigationBar';
import Footer from './footer/Footer';

interface LayoutProps {
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ title, description, children }) => {
     return (
          <>
               <Helmet>
                    <title>{title ? title + " - React Boilerplate" : "React.js Boilerplate"}</title>
                    <meta name="description" content={description || "React.js Boilerplate"} />
               </Helmet>
               <NavigationBar />
               <main className="container">
                    {children}
               </main>
               <Footer />
          </>
     );
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, for title, description it will work.
But for children will the String work?